# UIPageControl to change URL of UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIWebView` on my page with a `UIPageControl`:

The UIPageControl only has two buttons / dots, when on the first I need the UIWebView to load (www.mywebsite.com/page1.html) and when on the second dot to load (www.mywebsite.com/page2.html)

Any help appreciated, have looked on the internet but can't seem to find anything like this.

Cheers,

Jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to add an action to the page control:

```
[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeURL:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then use a switch statement or an if/else if and the index of the pageControl to determine what URL to use, then reload the webview.

Another route (easier maybe?) would be to create a "dot" image and just use custom UIButtons to make this happen.  Set the buttons to "selected" when they're pressed, etc.